# CNN with different input scales

Tags: input, neural-network, size, convolution, keras

I want to design a Conv. net for a multiscale classification problem. My aim is to train the CNN on a one input size and use that model to predict images of different scales/sizes. 
Is this possible with CNNs? I am using keras/python to develop my network?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Once the network is configured and trained, you cannot change its structure. For your problem, you will need to resize your other images to be the same size as your training images in order to use the trained network for classification.